# If key contain substring in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I have a more different type of keys in dict (there is no need to type values too)

```
'PL-1/KK-1/FO-1'
'PL-1/KK-2/GH-3'
'PL-1/KK-2'
'PL-1/KK-1/FO-4'
```

And I need a condition

```
if exist (key.split('/')[2])
do something 
return data
else:
do something
return data
```

Desired output:
In the first condition, all keys make entries except `'PL-1/KK-2'`.

Is there in python something like 'exist'?

Comment: what if we have this key `'PL-1/KK-2/'` ?

Comment: It  can't be that key. This is parsed XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no 'exists' operator.

In your case you should just test slashes:

```
if key.count('/') >= 2:
    # ...
```

If you need to have the components of the key, store and test the length:

```
components = key.split('/')
if len(components) >= 2:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def has_key(i_dict, i_filter):
    return any(k for k in i_dict.iterkeys() if i_filter(k))

# be it a dict called my_dict
# you could call it like 
has_key(my_dict, lambda x: x.count("/") == 2)
# or
has_key(my_dict, lambda x: len(x.split("/"))==2)
```

here's a little test

```
>>> my_dict = {"a":1,"c":3}
>>> has_key(my_dict, lambda k:k=="a")
True
>>> has_key(my_dict, lambda k:k=="c")
True
>>> has_key(my_dict, lambda k:k=="x")
False
```

Comment: the OP considers to `do something` on each key

Comment: After reading it again, I think you are right. The "human language" seems to state that, although the "code"  was not pointing that.